# How to set the Google Analytics cookie only after another consent cookie is set and "true"?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, cookies, google-analytics, next.js

I am using React/Nextjs for my website and the react-cookie-consent library. It creates a pop up where the user can agree to the cookie policy. If agreed, a cookie is set: CookieConsent with value "true".

Additionally, I want to use Google Analytics to track users if they agree (click Accept on the popup).

But it doesnt work: The Google Analytic cookies _ga and G_ENABLED_IDPS are set before the user clicks on the pop up.

Funny thing is, I only realized that on the Microsoft Edge Browser. In Chrome, these cookies are not set before the user gives consent.

This is my current code in _document.js:

```html
<Head>
          {/* Global Site Tag (gtag.js) - Google Analytics */}
          <script
            async
            src={`https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=${GA_TRACKING_ID}`}
          />
          <script
            dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
              __html: `
            window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
            function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}            
            gtag('js', new Date());
            
          `}}
          />
          
          <script type="text/javascript" src="/static/blockReactDevTools.js" />
          
          <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Cabin&display=swap" rel="stylesheet" />

</Head>
```

I played around using some hints from the internet, and came up with this version which also doesn't work:

```html
<Head>
          {/* Global Site Tag (gtag.js) - Google Analytics */}
          <script 
            async
            src={`https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=${GA_TRACKING_ID}`}
          />

          <script        
            dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
                __html: `
              
              var gtagId = '${GA_TRACKING_ID}';

              window['ga-disable-' + gtagId] = true;

              window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];

              function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}   

              gtag('js', new Date());

              function getCookie(cname) {
                var name = cname + "=";
                var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
                for(var i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) {
                  var c = ca[i];
                  while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') {
                    c = c.substring(1);
                  }
                  if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) {
                    return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
                  }
                }
                return "";
              }

              window.addEventListener("load", function() {
                var isCookieConsentTrue = getCookie("CookieConsent") == 'true';

                if(isCookieConsentTrue){
                    window['ga-disable-' + gtagId] = false;
                    alert("Cookie Consent given!");
                    
                  }  else {
                    alert("Cookie Consent NOT given!");
                    window['ga-disable-' + gtagId] = true;
                  }
              });          
            
            `}}
          />

          <script type="text/javascript" src="/static/blockReactDevTools.js" />

          
          <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Cabin&display=swap" rel="stylesheet" />

</Head>
```

I don't know if this is a nextjs specific issue, or something plain stupid general.

Can anyone guide me to a working solution?

EDIT: I tried the "Universal Analytics" approach of the suggestion. Suggested Solution make my helper functions to log events and pageviews fail (see below). Do I need also the gtag manager?

[image]

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The way you were doing it is Opt-out. The GA cookie is always set, as soon as the client requests the gtag.js. This however doesn't comply with GDPR. What you should look into is **Opt-in**, so that no GA cookie is set without consenting.

The general idea is to async load the gtag.js once the client has consented. For full functionality of gtag functions you have to load the gtag.js on every page-load if the client already consented. Best practice to do this is with a cookieconsent cookie set on consent. 
There's a widely used js library for this, which generates a popup and sets the consent-cookie for you.

**Reference:**
https://www.osano.com/cookieconsent/documentation/javascript-api/
You can generate code for the layout of your cookie banner by clicking **Start Coding** here:
https://www.osano.com/cookieconsent/download/
https://github.com/osano/cookieconsent/blob/dev/examples/example-7-javascript-api.html

Following code has to be implemented on every page in the `<head>` section:

```js
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/cookieconsent2/3.1.1/cookieconsent.min.css" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/cookieconsent2/3.1.1/cookieconsent.min.js" data-cfasync="false"></script>
<script>
var popup;
window.addEventListener('load', function(){
  window.cookieconsent.initialise({
   //set revokeBtn if you don't want to see a tiny pullup bar overlapping your website
   //if revokeBtn is set, make sure to include a link to cookie settings in your footer
   //you can open your banner again with: popup.open();
   //revokeBtn: "<div class='cc-revoke'></div>",
   type: "opt-in",
   theme: "classic",
   palette: {
       popup: {
           background: "#000",
           text: "#fff"
        },
       button: {
           background: "#fd0",
           text: "#000"
        }
    },
    onInitialise: function(status) {
      // request gtag.js on page-load when the client already consented
      if(status == cookieconsent.status.allow) setCookies();
    },
    onStatusChange: function(status) {
      // resquest gtag cookies on a new consent
      if (this.hasConsented()) setCookies();
      else deleteCookies(this.options.cookie.name)
    },
/* enable this to hide the cookie banner outside GDPR regions
    law: {
      regionalLaw: false,
    },
    location: true,
    },
*/
    function (p) {
        popup = p;
  })
});

//it is absolutely crucial to define gtag in the global scope
window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
gtag('js', new Date());
gtag('config', '${GA_TRACKING_ID}', {'anonymize_ip': true});

function setCookies() {
    var s = document.createElement('script');
    s.type = "text/javascript"
    s.async = "true";
    s.src = "https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=${GA_TRACKING_ID}";
    var x = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    x.parentNode.insertBefore(s, x);

    // you can add facebook-pixel and other cookies here
};

function deleteCookies(cookieconsent_name) {
        var keep = [cookieconsent_name, "DYNSRV"];

        document.cookie.split(';').forEach(function(c) {
            c = c.split('=')[0].trim();
            if (!~keep.indexOf(c))
                document.cookie = c + '=;' + 'expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 UTC;path=/';
        });
};
</script>
```

**Note:** 
Make sure that the gtag.js is loaded on every page-load once the consent-cookie was set to *allow*. Use `event_callback` to see if a gtag event was sent. You can use the gtag function without checking for the consent-cookie. If gtag.js is not present it just adds elements to the `window.dataLayer` without any functionality. To avoid errors, the `function gtag()` has to be declared in global scope and before use.

```js
// cookie-check is not necessary when gtag is in global scope
//if(popup.hasConsented()) { 
    gtag('event', 'sign_up', {
            'method': 'Google',
            'event_callback': function(){alert('event was sent');}
        });
//}
```

You don't have to send an extra pageview event, unless you want to manually specify the path. `setCookies()` already sends the current document path along with the config

Comment: I tried your code, but now my helper functions which log pageviews and events fail: check my edit in the original post please

Comment: I lack simple basic understanding how everything is connected together it seems. Does google analytics just count pageviews? Can't I register events via that or do I need the google tag manager? This is all very confusing.

Comment: E.g. I don understand why you suggest three different approaches. Do I have to choose only one? Can I combine Universal Analytics with gtag (which I need it seems)?

Comment: For your understanding: main reason to use GA is to count unique visitors and divide them into new or returning + some additional analytics. Without cookies, you wouldn't be able to differ from new or returning users. You could differ by IP and some other methods, but it's also not legal to store the IP without consent and peoples IPs are changing or there could be multiple users behind one IP. That's why you would want to get a users consent to store cookies. You can choose whatever method you'd like, i recommend to go with gtag because it's the successor of the universal method

Comment: Thank you for your efforts. I awarded you the bonus. But I have still questions like: How to count pageviews on other pages of my side? Do pageview counts happen automatically now when the user sets the cookie?How can I count now Events when I have to remove the code I posted in my edit?

Comment: @flo Thanks for the bounty. I will add some code tomorrow to work with pageviews

Comment: Think I figured it out: I use your "gtag" version of the code. That means, the function gtag is set on the window object when the user clicks Accept. Additionally, in the_app.js (next-specific, its a container of every page) in the componentDidMount section, I also set gtag function, but only if the cookie ConsentCookie = true. (This Cookie is set by react-cookie-consent automatically when user accepts). Can you confirm this is a correct approach? It seems to work.

Comment: I'm working on another solution. What's wrong about the current one, is that it only loads the gtag js after giving consent, but not anymore once it was accepted, so your gtag calls on other pages would be without any function

Comment: Yes but that was what i just said I think I solved. After giving Consent, the cookie ConsentCookie is set (to true). Now, every time a page loads, the next-specifix _app  is loaded (container around all pages). Within the componentDidMount function of the _app.js, I always check if cookie CookieConsent is set to true. If yes, I attach the gtag function to the window and can use it.

Comment: @flo please check the updated answer and make sure everything works fine with the `event_callback` code. I'm quite sure your call to gtag just pushed the events on the dataLayer but there was no gtag.js to pop and send them to GA. You can sniff http requests to googletagmanager.com in chrome via DevTools (F12)->Network. You can remove react-cookie-consent because it doesn't have a callback on page-load if the consent was already given. cookieconsent3 is way better and used by millions of websites. Upvotes appreciated ;)

Comment: Hey @5andr0 I think the nesting/parethesys structure here is broken. What's that is that `function (p) { popup [etc..]` meant to do?

Because of that it's not clear whether the `window.dataLayer` part should happen inside or outside the on 'load' event listener. Could you please check?

Answer (score 28):

Use gtag's [consent config options](https://developers.google.com/gtagjs/devguide/consent). Currently, the following can be put before any data measurement commands (`config` or `event`) are run in the header:

```js
gtag('consent', 'default', {
  'ad_storage': 'denied',
  'analytics_storage': 'denied'
});
```

Then run this once the user has approved or if a consent cookie is present:

```js
gtag('consent', 'update', {
  'ad_storage': 'granted',
  'analytics_storage': 'granted'
});
```

If you use Facebook Pixel, it works in a similar way. E.g. `fbq('consent', 'revoke');` then `fbq('consent', 'grant')`.

Comment: This is the actual answer.

Comment: This is not GDPR compliant! When loading the script, information is already exchanged without the user opting in.