# Cookie Consent Banner

Tags: javascript, jquery

There is a `<script>` for the google analytics cookies within the `<head>` code:

```
<!-- Google Tag Manager -->
<script>
   (function(w,d,s,l,i){w[l]=w[l]||[];
   w[l].push({'gtm.start': new Date().getTime(),event:'gtm.js'});
   var f=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0], j=d.createElement(s),dl=l!='dataLayer'?'&l='+l:'';
   j.async=true;j.src='https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id='+i+dl;
   f.parentNode.insertBefore(j,f); })
   (window,document,'script','dataLayer','GTM-53DTW8N');
</script>
<!-- End Google Tag Manager -->
```

I need to make a cookie consent banner that only when user accepts cookies, the cookies will send and we can see it show in the dev tool's Application.

I had manually blocked the third-party cookies from loading or sending when the page loads; by adding
`type="text/plain" data-categories="analytics"` to the `<script>` attributes.

So now the script looks like this:

```
<!-- Google Tag Manager -->
<script type="text/plain" data-categories="analytics">
   (function(w,d,s,l,i){w[l]=w[l]||[];
   w[l].push({'gtm.start': new Date().getTime(),event:'gtm.js'});
   var f=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0], j=d.createElement(s),dl=l!='dataLayer'?'&l='+l:'';
   j.async=true;j.src='https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id='+i+dl;
   f.parentNode.insertBefore(j,f); })
   (window,document,'script','dataLayer','GTM-53DTW8N');
</script>
<!-- End Google Tag Manager -->
```

I want to know if I can make it so that on click of a button, the regular `<script>` for cookies will load only after user accepts cookies?
Do I call the cookie script by using an external .js file within the same folder?

I'd appreciate any help for this. Thank you!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67774259/3684265

Comment: @imvain2 thank you so much! i managed to make it work!