# Loading Google Analytics after the user consents to cookie usage

Tags: javascript, cookies, google-analytics, cookieconsent

I am trying to implement a cookie consent for a website that uses Google Analytics. How can I load Analytics only after the user agrees to the use of cookies? Or, is there another approach I should be taking?

I tried dynamically loading the GA script, but I get gtag undefined afterwards.

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60173853/how-to-set-the-google-analytics-cookie-only-after-another-consent-cookie-is-set) answer your question?